# how to check null values using if condition in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have multiple conditions in my IF statement but only the second one works in other words the null values is not detected.  i know the fields are blank or null but it is not detecting it.  The email is fired only if keep the 2nd condition and remove the first one but i want to check both conditions before i sent the email out.  thanks    here is my code

```
string k = gr.Cells[9].Text;
DateTime strExpectedSubDate = DateTime.Parse(gr.Cells[3].Text);
DateTime strDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

if (k == null && strExpectedSubDate < strDate)
{
    send email();
```

Comment: I would suspect `Text` does not return null here.. gravity exists. Check the initial assumptions - preferably with a debugger.

Comment: Have you considered that `k` might be an empty string? =)

Comment: i think you are right i don't see null when i put it in debug mode but the value i see like this and i don't know what it means: "&nbsp"

Comment: `&nbsp;` is HTML code for a space character (specifically, a "non-breaking space"). The lesson here is never to rely on what you see - use a debugger or some other in-code mechanism to find out what's really there.

Comment: Also, if you feel you've answered your own question, accept your answer as "the" answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(k) && strExpectedSubDate < strDate)`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to change to:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(k) && strExpectedSubDate < strDate)
```

Or:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(k) && strExpectedSubDate < strDate)
```

Which equals to:

```
if ((k == null || k == string.Empty) && strExpectedSubDate < strDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(k) && strExpectedSubDate < strDate)
{
 // send email

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you've got is fine for checking if k is null.
If you also want to check if it's empty try:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(k) && strExpectedSubDate < strDate)
{
    SendEmail();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this is how i solved my problem

```
if (K == ("&nbsp;") && strExpectedSubDate < strDate)
and it worked fine.  thanks
```